# How can I retrieve a JDBC NUMERIC column value that may be NULL, without incurring a conversion cost?

Tags: java, performance, jdbc

I have a simple query using JDBC of an Oracle database which is proving slow to retrieve, even though the query itself doesn't seem to be the problem. A profiler reveals that a lot of time is spent in:

```
ResultSet#getString(String)
```

methods, some of which are retrieving Oracle `NUMBER` columns which are of Java `long` precision, or thereabouts. These values may also be null.

I am guessing that `getString(String)` is slow when returning a column value that is defined as a number - and thought about using `getLong(String)` but of course that returns a primitive that cannot be null.

Is there a better way? Can a JDBC `NUMERIC` value be returned as an object without converting it to a `String` or incurring any other conversion cost?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this?

```
long value = resultSet.getLong(colName);
if (resultSet.wasNull()) {
   return null;
} else {
   return Long.valueOf(value);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I suppose it's not reasonable for me to have gripes about the JDBC API at this stage in the game. It does seem not optimal to have to carry out two operations for this.

Comment: @EBCDIC: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777214/when-accessing-resultsets-in-jdbc-is-there-an-elegant-way-to-distinguish-between